# How to find status of records loaded when we forcefully intercepting batch execution by stopping mssql database

Tags: java, database, jooq

We are implementing connection or flush retry logic for database.
Auto-commit=true;

```
RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy()
                .retryOn(DataAccessException.class)
                .withMaxRetries(maxRetry)
                .withDelay(retryInterval, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            result = Failsafe.with(retryPolicy)
                .onFailure(throwable -> LOG.warn("Flush failure, will not retry. {} {}"
                    , throwable.getClass().getName(), throwable.getMessage()))
                .onRetry(throwable -> LOG.warn("Flush failure, will retry. {} {}"
                    , throwable.getClass().getName(), throwable.getMessage()))
                .get(cntx -> {
                    return batch.execute();
                });
```

we want to intercept storing, updating, inserting, deleting records by stopping mssql db service in backend. At some point even If we got org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException, some of the records in batch (subset of batch) are loaded into db.

Is there any way to find failed and successfully loaded records using jooq api?

Comment: What kinds of exceptions are those?

Comment: @LukasEder, Our testcases are: #1 Plug and unplug the internet connection #2 Db sevice stop and start.


Exception received:
Caused by: org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [merge into \"dbo\".\"file150\" using (select 1 [one]) as dummy_82901439([one]) on (ID=?) when matched then update set [NAME] = ?, [TEAM] = ?, [BATCHID] = ? when not matched then insert ([ID], [NAME], [TEAM], [BATCHID]) values (?, ?, ?, ?);]; Connection is closed

Answer (score 0):

The jOOQ API cannot help you here out of the box because such a functionality is definitely out of scope for the relatively low level jOOQ API, which helps you write type safe embedded SQL. It does not make any assumptions about your business logic or infrastructure logic.

Ideally, you will run your own diagnostic here. For example, you already have a `BATCHID` column which should make it possible to detect which records were inserted/updated with which process. When you re-run the batch, you need to detect that you've already attempted this batch, remember the previous `BATCHID`, and fetch the `IDs` of the previous attempt to do whatever needs to be done prior to a re-run.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response @Lukas Eder. 

My question for you is: Why org.jooq.Batch.execute() is not throwing java.sql.BatchUpdateException when we interrupt the batch execution by stop db service/removing internet connection?. 

If it throws BatchUpdateException then I could have catch updatedRowCount by calling getUpdateCounts() on batchUpdateException obj. Expecting this kind of feature in future release.

Comment: Not sure. Maybe report a bug? https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new Ideally accompanied by https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ-mcve

Comment: For the reference, the reported issue is here: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8481